# What are the principal components of a set of points lying on a circle?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, geometry

So if there are a set of points lying on a circle (2 dimensional), what will be the principal components given that the variance of points vary equally along any 2 perpendicular directions

Comment: My intuition says that it will still be a circle.  You can confirm this by generating  equally spaced points on the circle and computing the transform.

Comment: @Demetri It depends on whether the means of the points in each direction are concentric and what "any two" means.  As an example of what could happen when "any two" means "there exist two," picture the dataset with one value of $(-1,0),$ eleven values of $(1,0),$ and twelve values of $(0.561, 0.828).$ You can verify the variances in the $x$ and $y$ directions are equal, yet there are two distinct PCs with different eigenvalues. If instead "any two" means "all," the question is trivial because it answers itself.